# Two drop down list, second one populated with values in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I need to make two drop down lists. Let's say the first one containing food categories: Ice Cream, Pizzas, Noodles, Milkshakes.

So if I pick ice cream the second drop down list would contain: Chocolate, Vanilla, Mint and so on. And if I pick Pizzas at the first one, I want this second one to change dynamically so that it would contain: Pepperoni, All Meat, and so on.

However, I need the second drop down list to be populated by the values I already have in my database. So let's say if I'm out of chocolate ice cream there would be no chocolate in the second drop down list. That is my desired outcome.

I am using HTML, PHP, JavaScript/jQuery, and MySQL so currently it's a webapp and these two drop down list are for me to delete values from the database. So let's say I want to delete Pepperoni from Pizzas, I would select Pizzas at the first drop down list and then Pepperoni at the second drop down list. Then I would click delete which would execute a js function to pass the parameters using ajax to PHP and then the delete query can be executed.

I am stuck on populating the second drop down list dynamically, any help on this? What I've done so far for the drop down is only:

```
                 <select id="tester_type">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="LMX">LMX</option>
                    <option value="LCX">LCX</option>
                    <option value="CAT">CAT</option>
                    <option value="J750">J750</option>
                    <option value="HPPS">HPPS</option>
                    <option value="HP93K">HP93K</option>
                    <option value="UFLEX">UFLEX</option>
                    <option value="IFLEX">IFLEX</option>
                    <option value="QRT">QUARTET</option>
                    <option value="TGR">TIGER</option>
                    <option value="ETS">ETS</option>
                    <option value="LEX">LEX</option>
                    <option value="HPLC">HPLC</option>
                    <option value="HPSS">HPSS</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>New Tester Name:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="tester_type">
                <!--Update list of available testers-->
            </select>
        </td>
```

Note: I just replaced the first drop down list as food category for a better understanding of my question by the way. Just take the first one as food categories and the second would be its type/flavors.

EDIT:

It doesn't display anything in the desired section/div in the window. Just a blank except for the title I have added in my HTML and other two buttons.

What I have done according to Brandon's answer:

In the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Delete Tester</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">displayDropDown();</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Delete Tester</h3>
        <div id="drop_two_list"></div>
        <table class="deleteTable">
            <tr>
                <td/><td><br>
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.close();"/>
                    <input type="button" name="send" value="Delete" onclick="deleteTester();"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the external javascript file:

```
function dislplayDropDown()
{
var page = "database.php";

$.post(page, {
    action : "dislplayDropDown"
    }, function(data) {
    $("div#drop_two_list").html(data);
    alert(data);
});
```

In the PHP:

```
function displayDropDown()
{
    $tester_info = "dummy_tester_list";
    $query_string = "select * from $tester_info";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<select id=\"tester_type\">";
    while($data)
    {
        echo "<option value='$data['tester_type']'>$data['tester_type']</option>"; // first drop down
    }
    echo "</select>";

    $selected_tester_type = $_REQUEST['tester_type'];

    $query_string = "select * from $tester_info where tester_type = $selected_tester_type";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<select>";
    while($data)
    {
        echo "option id=\"tester_name\" value='$data['tester_name']'>$data['tester_name']</option>"// second drop down
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

?>
<?php

$action = rtrim($_REQUEST['action']);

if($action=="insert")//This is for some other function
{
    $tester_type = rtrim($_REQUEST['tester_type']);
    $tester_name  = rtrim($_REQUEST['tester_name']);

    echo checkDuplicateTesterName($tester_type, $tester_name);
}
else if($action=="displayDropDown")
{
    echo displayDropDown();
}


?>
```

Here's the table structure as requested by Kentot, it's only the first five rows because there's more than 500 rows so I wouldn't want to put the whole thing here:

```
  id    tester_type   tester_name
   1        LMX          LMX-01
   2        LMX          LMX-04
   3        LMX          LMX-05
   4        LMX          LMX-06
   5        LMX          LMX-07
```

Comment: can you post your mysql table structure?

Comment: Alright, just posted.

Comment: Note that unless there are a very large range of options, it may be more efficient to grab the whole data set in one query and handle everything else in application code (either php or JavaScript) - until the submit button is pressed anyway

Comment: @Strawberry Alright but how do I do that? Would you mind showing me a suggestion? I'm still figuring it out. The closest answer that I've arrived at to what I desire is Brandon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can create this table say we will call this "menu"

```
food_id     |  food_type_flavor   |  food_category
--------------------------------------------
1           |   chocolate         |  ice cream
2           |   vanilla           |  ice cream
3           |   lemon             |  juice
```

and in your code you can create this

```
$query = mysql_query("Select * from menu");
echo "<select name='food_category' >";
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   echo "<option value='$test['food_category']'>$test['food_category']</option>"; // first drop down
}
echo "</select>";
```

then when you select category you can get what was the food_category being selected and you can use that variable to make your second drop down

```
 $selected_category = $_POST['food_category'];

$query = mysql_query("Select * from menu where food_category ='$selected_category'");
echo "<select>";

while($test = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{


echo "<option name='food_flavor_type' value='$test['food_type_flavor]' >$test['food_type_flavor']</option>"; // second drop down
}
echo"</select>";
```

Comment: There seems to be some error in your code. Do you mean `echo "<option value=\"$test['food_category']\">$test['food_category']</option>"; // first drop down` ?

Comment: @hzq yes it would be value = ' '   not value = " "

Comment: or you could echo it like this:
echo "<option value='{$test['food_category']}'>{$test['food_category']}</option>";

Comment: Hmmm something seems to be wrong some where, I'll post up the edit in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Hai hzq I have made modification in your code for me to answer it cleaner:

your HTML:

```
 <?php

        $result = mysql_query("select * from dummy_tester_list");
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    ?>

    <select id="tester_type">
       <?php foreach($data as $d): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $d["tester_type"]?>"><?php $d["tester_type"];?></option>
       <?php endforeach ?>                     
    </select>
<section id="tester_name">

</section>

     <h3>Delete Tester</h3>
        <table class="deleteTable">
            <tr>
                <td><div id="drop_two_list"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="DELETE_TESTER_POPUP.close();"/>
                    <input type="button" name="send" value="Submit" onclick="deleteTester();"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Your PHP where you want to get the list of the selected tester type:

```
<?php
    $tester_type = $_POST["tester_name"];
    $query = mysql_query("select * from tester_info where tester_type = {$tester_type}");
    $select_dropdown;
    $select_dropdown .= "<select name='tester_lists'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $select_dropdown .= "<option>{$row["tester_name"]}</option>";
    }
    $select_dropdown .= "</select>";

    echo $select_dropdown;

?>
```

Your jquery when you change the tester name and get the equivalent tester list

```
$("body").on("change","#tester_type",function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "dropdowns.php", // your php file
            type: "POST",
            data: tester_name: $(this).val(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#tester_name").html(data);
            } 
        });

   });
```

Comment: Hmm I don't think I can do it this way. The reason I'm sending `action` in ajax(as shown in my edit) is because in my PHP file I have other functions as well. The `action` is to tell the PHP file which function to execute(as shown in the last part of the edit). My main purpose is for the HTML file to contain only HTML codes and so that it would be much safer(?) in case the user views source on his/her browser.

Comment: your <?php?> codes or scripts could not be viewed when user view your source code

Comment: Ohh I see. But is there really a way to put the PHP codes only in the PHP file? I really want the HTML file to contain only HTML codes. Brandon's answer would be the closest to what I desire but it's just that my ajax(in the edited question) javascript function doesn't seem to be executing. Is there perhaps a mistake there or something else?

Comment: I could not see any ajax script in your post

Comment: I meant jQuery*, my bad.

Comment: Can you try this code?   

function dislplayDropDown()
    {
    var page = "database.php";
    $.ajax({
            url: page,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                 $("div#drop_two_list").html(data);
                 alert(data);
            } 
        });
    
    }

Comment: Yes I have added. I edited the HTML to show. My other js functions are working. Only `displayDropDown()` function is not.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one ..

```
<?php
function displayDropDown()
{
    $tester_info = "dummy_tester_list";
    $query_string = "select * from $tester_info";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<select id=\"tester_type\">";
    while($data)
    {
        ?>
        <option><?php echo $data['tester_type']; ?></option>
   <?php
    }
    echo "</select>";

    $selected_tester_type = $_REQUEST['tester_type'];

    $query_string = "select * from $tester_info where tester_type = $selected_tester_type";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<select>";
    while($data)
    {
    ?>
        <option><?php echo $data['tester_name']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

?>
<?php

$action = rtrim($_REQUEST['action']);

if($action=="insert")//This is for some other function
{
    $tester_type = rtrim($_REQUEST['tester_type']);
    $tester_name  = rtrim($_REQUEST['tester_name']);

    echo checkDuplicateTesterName($tester_type, $tester_name);
}
else if($action=="displayDropDown")
{
    echo displayDropDown();
}


?>
```

so we separate the tag to remove the error

Comment: Hmm there doesn't seem to be any change and there's no errors as well. The `displayDropDown();` function in my HTML file doesn't seem to be executing though. Is there perhaps an error in my ajax javascript?

Comment: why do you have to make a js displayDropDown() function and call in your php when you can directly make it with your HTML ?

Comment: I did call it in my HTML. The two functions in the js and the PHP just have the same name. The jQuery sends an action to the PHP file whereby it would read and execute the appropriate functions I want. That's because I don't only have this one function in my PHP file, I have other functions so that's why I use an `action` variable to determine which function to execute.

Comment: Brandon, are you still able to help me out? I will literally paste my whole codes if I have to. I am in desperate need of help.

Comment: I see you are using pure java script hmmm.. let me check you code

Comment: I used IE's web debugger to check, my function doesn't execute. My other functions in the same js file works fine.